# Lemmatizing "I'm" to "I" using nltk

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am using nltk's wordnet_lemmatizer. Ideally, the word "I'm" should be getting lemmatized to "I".

I have tried the following POS taggers:

```
wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize("I'm", wordnet.ADV)
wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize("I'm", wordnet.ADJ)
wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize("I'm", wordnet.VERB)
wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize("I'm", wordnet.NOUN)enter code here
```

All of them return "I'm" instead of "I",
Any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/fork-of-basic-nlp-with-nltk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokenize and POS tag first, then use the tag as the `pos` argument input for `WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize()`

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> 
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> 
>>> def penn2morphy(penntag):
...     """ Converts Penn Treebank tags to WordNet"""
...     morphy_tag = {'NN':'n', 'JJ':'a',
...                   'VB':'v', 'RB':'r'}
...     try:
...         return morphy_tag[penntag[:2]]
...     except:
...         return 'n' # default to Nouns.
...     
... 
>>> def lemmatize_sent(tokenized_sent):
...     return [wnl.lemmatize(word.lower(), penn2morphy(tag)) for word, tag in pos_tag(tokenized_sent)]
... 
>>> lemmatize_sent("I'm")
['i', "'", 'm']
```